# Javascript's sort() not returning in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Javascript's sort() returns **[19,20,2000,500]** when applied to **[20,19,500,2000]**. Why is it considering **2000** to be less than **500**?

```
var arr = [20,19,500,2000];
arr.sort();
arr;
// [19, 20, 2000, 500]
```

Comment: "The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2):

Javascript by default treat elements of `array` as `string`. So, when sorting `19`, `720`, `5` it'll get the **first** character from it and sorts in order. like `19, 5, 720`.

```
var arr = [20,19,500,2000];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
})
```

[More Details](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=103)

[More on Sorting](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-array-sorting/)

Comment: No, it does not look at just the first character.